# How to subtract gravity from raw acceleration of an MPU9250 - 9DOF IMU

Tags: sensor, filter, accelerometer, speed, gravity

I'm working with an MPU9250 and using the Madgwick Filter. For what I know I need to subtract the GRAVITY from my X, Y, Z Acceleration values, basically, some kind of gravity compensation to get linear acceleration values. I was using the following code (q is my quaternion generated by the Madgwick filter):

```
 g[0] = 2 * (q[1] * q[3] - q[0] * q[2])
 g[1] = 2 * (q[0] * q[1] + q[2] * q[3])
 g[2] = q[0] * q[0] - q[1] * q[1] - q[2] * q[2] + q[3] * q[3]
```

Then, to compensate the gravity, I subtract gx, gy, gz from my ax, ay, az values respectively. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to solve this problem and I would like a bit of help. After stripping the gravity values, I need to get velocity. I don't need position so I'm not going to double integrate the acceleration values. By the way, I have to mention that this will be used to measure speed and acceleration/deceleration of football players while running, so I don't need this to be extremely precise.

PS: I read about using a Low-Pass filter to subtract gravity, but I'm not sure if I should be doing that.

Comment: Have you read this post yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617200/remove-gravity-from-imu-accelerometer

Comment: Yes I did, but that guy used a Kalman Filter, the Madwick algorithm gets me a different quaternion and thats my question. Im not sure if I should be rotating the quaternion. The guy on that question was using a 6DOF IMU and I have a 9DOF IMU, so thats why I am able to use the Madgwick Filter with my Magnetometer inputs.

Also what I really want to understand are these three lines of code In my post and why they work (well, that is what [this guy](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/simple-gravity-compensation-9-dom-imus) said)

Comment: I'd try a steep low pass filter, with a cutoff of less than 0.2Hz.

Comment: Can the low pass filter remove the gravity from the accelerometer values? Should I apply it to the accelerometer raw data?

Comment: Yes.  Apply it to the raw signal.